# Is there any way to change link that comes from notification in webview using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

> I'm using webview widget in my flutter app I want to change and open a
> link when user tap on notification, the link is static because I test
> this , I tried to make this but it doesn't work my code :

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  dynamic url = "https://google.com";
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  @override
  void initState() {
    configureCallBacks();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: WebViewScaffold(
      Url: url,
    ));
  }
```

> this is code for notification

```
  void configureCallBacks() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (message) async {
        // running when user open the app
        print('onMessage :$message ');
        setState(() {
          url = 'https://youtube.com';
        });
      },
      onResume: (message) async {
        String data = message['data']['ali'];
        print('onResume : $data');
          url = 'https://facebook.com';
      },
      onLaunch: (message) async {
        print('onLaunch : $message');
        setState(() {
          url = 'https://twitter.com';
        });
      }, 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: webview\_flutter update url in same webview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246081/flutter-webview-flutter-update-url-in-same-webview-widget)

Comment: what can i replace of onWebViewCreated in webViewScaffold instead of WebView ??